# How to specify exact matching in GnuPG 2.1's--quick-sign-key?

Tags: gnupg

GnuPG 2.1 has the nice feature *unattendded key-signing*. However, its matching seems to be somewhat fuzzy. E.g, if I have two user IDs like 'Foo' and 'Foo Bar' on a key with fingerprint FPR, `gpg --quick-sign key FPR Foo` will sign both. Can I force it to do exact matching?

Answer (score 0):

Originally, GnuPG has [different notions to specify substring matches](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Specify-a-User-ID.html), exact matches, matching mail addresses and so on, which I also discussed in [*How to get GnuPG fingerpints only for specified key name, not for substring matches?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/117575/19837).

From my experiments, those do not work for `--quick-sign-key` (in your case, you should be able to select the specific user ID using the selector `='Foo'`, which at least does not work for user IDs containing whitespace). This seems a bad limitation of GnuPG, which in my opinion even makes this command unusable for its intended purpose, as you cannot reliably select specific user IDs any more. I'd recommend opening a [bug report](https://bugs.gnupg.org/gnupg/) for this.

Comment: I gave bad examples. Gnupg actually won't accept Foo cuz that's too short. However, supposing I have `Voldemort` and `Voldemort, the Dark Lord`. My gpg2.1 (git master) won't accept `=Voldemort` and `Voldemort` will sign both of the uids. I had tried it before as the manpage somewhat indicates `=` might force exact matching and now I've reconfirmed (with another example setup) that it doesn't in this case.

Comment: Sadly, I can't uid hashes (as shown with `-k --with-colons`) don't work either .

Comment: If there _is_ a way, it clearly lacks documentation. I wasn't aware of the user ID hashes yet, but I also haven't been able to use them.